# A function to find how many times string 1 contains string 2 c++

Tags: c++, string, count, contains

I want to check how many times my first string contains the second string.
I read about it in the internet, and i found a function name std::find, i tried to use it and i failed...

```
std::string Str1 = "Hello Hello";
std::string Str2 = "ll";
Now what?
```

I tried to use

> std::count

as well but i found out that its work just on a letters.

```
counter = std::count(Str1.begin(), Str2.end(), Str2); // dident work
```

Help??

Edit:
Thats what i am trying to do:

```
unsigned int Nucleus::get_num_of_codon_appearances(const std::string& codon) const
{
    unsigned int counter = 0;
    counter = std::count(this->_DNA_strand.begin(), this->_DNA_strand.end(), codon);
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Please show how you tried to use `std::find()`.

Comment: I dident found a good use for my question..

Comment: Edit: Added my try

Comment: To clarify one requirement, when you find a match, do you start again from the next character or from the end of the match? As a concrete example, does `AAA` contain one or two `AA`s?

Comment: If i had ABCEYHABC, so the function found the first abc and running to the next ABC, the outpot will be: 2.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this quite easily with std::regex if you are using c++11 or greater.

Something like,

```
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const string str = "one two hello three four hello five hello";

    regex re("hello");
    cout << "Number of hellos : " <<  
        distance(sregex_iterator(str.begin(),str.end(), re),sregex_iterator());

}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/IXZ5Vb)

Comment: Please as some explanation as I've never seen `sregex_iterator` before, and I'm pretty sure neither has the OP.

Comment: I tried your way and its doesnet work well...
i gonna post my code for you to understand more

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::string::find.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

size_t count (const string & src, const string & str) {
    size_t cnt = 0, fnd = 0;
    while (fnd = (src.find(str, fnd)) != string::npos) {
        cnt++; fnd++;
    }
    return cnt;
}

...

count("Hello, world!", "ll");
```

Comment: I dident understand so well your code, but i'm not interest to build a function  - i want to use a builld-in function for that.

Answer (score 0):

As [paxbun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036976/a-function-to-find-how-many-times-string-1-contains-string-2-c/53037051#53037051) stated the string::find method is used there and that is a built-in function of the string class.

Reference of the .find() Method [string::find ~ C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

As another approach including a class corresponding to your code above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//class declaration
class Nucleus{
private:
 string _DNA_strand{"ABCADDASDASABCAFGDACCACABCDA"};

public:
    const string get_codon(){return _DNA_strand;} //accessor of private variable
    unsigned int get_num_of_codon_appearances(const string& _DNA_strand, const string& ) const;
};

//Function  to return the number of times a string is found within another string.
unsigned int Nucleus::get_num_of_codon_appearances(const string& codon, const string& c) const
{
    unsigned int count = 0; //sets count
    size_t counter = 0; //sets counter
    while (counter != string::npos) // if counter does not equal string no position
    {
            size_t i = counter + c.length(); // sets i to counter + length of searched for object
            counter = codon.find(c, i); // .find() method 
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

//Main Function
int main()
{
    Nucleus temp; //sets the object temp of the class Nucleus
    const string codon = temp.get_codon();
    const string c = "ABC";

    cout << "The Number of times " << c << " is found in " 
    << temp.get_codon() << " is: " << temp.get_num_of_codon_appearances(codon, c) << endl;

    return 0;   
}
```

Example output:

```
The Number of times ABC is found in ABCADDASDASABCAFGDACCACABCDA is: 3
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/5rXe4h)